Can I host Strapi v4 without pushing on github
I created a ecommerce website with next js and strapi and now I want to deploy my web but to deploy strapi we need to push the project on the github repo and this will make my ecommerce web code publically available and I thought to make my repo private then it will work or not I am confused in it.
Thanks in advance
Host strapi without pushing it on github

There is no need to push the code to github publicly. You can host the strapi build the same way you can host any other nodejs based project.
